# Emacs elpy doesn't find pyflakes package

Tags: python-2.7, emacs24, elpy

I'm reinstalling emacs24 on a remote server and can't seem to replicate my personal configuration and get it running.

I've installed the following pip packages using pip install --user (I don't have root on the server):
jedi, flake8, autopep8, rope, importmagic

Then I installed elpy using these lines in the .emacs config file:

;==============

; Use MELPA repository

(require 'package)
;; Any add to list for package-archives (to add marmalade or melpa) goes here
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("MELPA" .
      "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

;==============

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))

Then I installed elpy from M-x package-list-packages and everything went well.
Everything is working except the in-buffer pep8 corrections.

My current elpy-config is:

Virtualenv........: None

RPC Python........: 2.7.6 (/usr/bin/python)

Interactive Python: ipython (/usr/local/bin/ipython)

Emacs.............: 24.3.1

Elpy..............: 1.10.0

Jedi..............: 0.9.0

Rope..............: 0.10.3

Importmagic.......: 0.1.3

Autopep8..........: 0.1.3

Syntax checker....: Not found (pyflakes)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I would love your help.
Thanks so much,
Shahar

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following path to my `.bashrc` file (in my home dir) solved my problem.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Under this path elpy was able to find the missing package